# Как поменять место где создается файл БД?

Tags: asp.net-core

По-умолчанию делатеся так:

Последовательно введем в это окно две команды. Сначала выполним команду:

```
Add-Migration Initial
```

Эта команда добавит в проект новую миграцию.

Затем выполним команду:

```
Update-Database
```

Эта команда по миграции Initial собственно сгенерирует базу данных.

И в итоге в папке текущего пользователя на диске С (`C:\Users\[Имя_пользователя]`) мы сможем найти два файла MobilesDB.mdf и MobilesDB.ldf, которые и представляют базу данных.

**Но мне нужно создавать в другом месте**

Answer (score -1):

Создайте базу сами вручную и подключите ее в файле appsettings.json (замените просто адрес базы старой)